# React rerender component A LOT of times performance

Tags: reactjs, redux, websocket

I'm developing an aplication using react that is receiving data from a web socket (this web socket will feed me with huge amounts of data, more than 500 records per second). My question is how would be the best way to handle this data rendered in a table.

Basically what we have is a table component that receives the data from redux and each field in the table is optimized with react.memo so the field that receive the same value does not rerender again.

Would a better solution be having the data stored directly in the component better than in redux? Is there a better solution (not redux or storing in component).

I know this could be a weird question but to be honest, I would love to hear other developers opinion.

Thanks very much

Comment: Assuming no components needlessly re render (your memo is working) then you could try to use [react-virtualized](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-virtualized) or [react-window](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-window). Try and make sure nothing is needlessly re rendered by making a mock socket that only adds some rows and console.log in your item component to see if it doesn't re render items it already has in the list.

Comment: Not sure why anyone would need a list that gets 500 new items every second since nobody is ever going to be able to read that. At least with something like facebook infinite scroll it only loads extra items when user scrolls down far enough.